# scala syntax highlighting in bluefish

Tags: scala, ubuntu

Scala comes packaged with bluefish syntax config in misc/scala-tool-support/bluefish/

I have attempted to configure this, as per the README, but there is no effect.

```
cp ~/.bluefish/highlighting ~/.bluefish/highlighting_
cat ~/.bluefish/highlighting_ /opt/scala/scala-2.7.7.final/misc/scala-tool-support/bluefish/highlighting  > ~/.bluefish/highlighting
```

I have ensured highlighting is turned on in the bluefish config.

I have not used bluefish before and am trying it for the first time because there is syntax highlighting support for it.

The README says any file I open that has a .scala extension will have the scala highlighting applied. Instead I see no highlighting.

UPDATE: The file type is not present in the document types menu. So perhaps the config is incorrect? This is [my bluefish highlighting file](http://gist.github.com/396740).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you refresh the highlighting in the bluefish editor?

See [Files Types](http://bluefish.openoffice.nl/manual/ch05s11.html#syntax-highlighting):

> While editing, Bluefish will only update the highlighting patterns in the block of text around the cursor.
>   The number of lines (the size) of this block can be adjusted in the preferences under `Editor`.
>   **The syntax highlighting for the total document can be refreshed using the `Document  → Update Highlighting` (<kbd>F5</kbd>) menu**.

Check also if the type of a file is properly detected. If not, you can change the type using the [`Document → Document Type` menu](http://bluefish.openoffice.nl/manual/ch08s10.html).

Comment: Thank you. The document type is not present in the menu. See revised question (config linked).

Comment: @Synesso: does highlighting works for other types declared in that highlighting file?

Answer (score 2):

Bluefish 2.2.10, now solved for me.

This is for anyone else suffering the same problem that Bluefish has not been showing syntax highlighting since I installed it, very frustrating!

So, just discovered that Syntax Highlighting has been moved from Preferences options (where it used to live) to the Document menu i.e. 'Highlight syntax' but that still didn't work until I selected Document, Language Mode and then selected PHP (or whatever you need).

Hope that helps others.